# Prolog syntax issue, space after negation

Tags: prolog

I have a strange  question with using negation in SWI Prolog. When I use the following code without a space after negation "\+", it gives an error:

```
2 ?- assert((only_child(X) :- mother(M,X),\+(mother(M,_),\+ X==_))).
true.

3 ?- only_child(cathy).
ERROR: only_child/1: Undefined procedure: (\+)/2
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         (\+)/1
Exception: (7) \+(mother(melody, _G2102), \+cathy==_G2107) ? creep
4 ?-
```

However if I use space after negation, it works perfectly fine.

```
2 ?- assert((only_child(X) :- mother(M,X),\+ (mother(M,_),\+ X==_))).
true.

3 ?- only_child(cathy).
false.

4 ?-
```

But the following code works fine for both, using space after "\+" and without using space.

```
4 ?- \+ father(michael,cathy).
false.

5 ?- \+father(michael,cathy).
false.

6 ?-
```

Can anyone please explain this to me? Its really very puzzling. I will be really thankful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The opening parenthesis is special when parsing Prolog. If there is no space between an identifier and an opening paren, the identifier is always treated as the name of a functor (even if it is not alphanumeric). Whatever is inside the parens is treated as a list of arguments for this functor.

However, if there is a space, the paren is treated in its normal, mathematical function of grouping expressions. The comma inside such an expression serves the role of a boolean `and` operator.

So:

```
"func(A,B)"  - OK - invoke `func` on parameters `A`, `B`    
"func (A,B)" - syntax error - interpreted as an identifier stuck together 
               with an AND expression    
"\+ (A,B)"   - OK - operator `\+` acting on `(A,B)` (A and B)    
"\+(A,B)"    - error - invoke `\+` with two parameters `A`, `B` 
               but \+ only takes one argument    
"\+(A)"      - OK - since `\+` takes one argument, it can 
               be invoked as a functor with one argument inside parens
```

The parser is also intelligent enough to split operators from identifiers (the first letter triggers a new token):

```
"\+ father(A,B)" - OK - invoke functor `father` with `A` and `B`, 
                   negate the result
"\+father(A,B)"  - still OK - the parser will stop reading the 
                   name of the operator when it encounters the 'f', 
                   so the result is same as above
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a clear explanation. This has really cleared my doubt.

Answer (score 3):

Prolog [requires](http://www.ifcomputer.co.jp/en/manuals5.2/refman/node482.html) a space ("delimiter") between an operator and a parenthesis.

If there is no space, the Prolog parser treats it as a functor with two parameters. The two cases below are no different to the parser.

```
mother(..., ...)
\+(..., ...)
```

However, if you put a space, the parser treats it as an operator and a parenthesized argument for it. There is a converse rule (there must be no space between the name of a functor and the parenthesis), making this line also produce an error:

```
mother (..., ...)
```

The rule of thumb is - if it's an operator, put a space after it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand what you said. However in the above case, when I don't use space \+(mother(...,...),\+ X==_) the parser should still treat \+ as a functor with two arguments which I have provided to it. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What I mean is that I have provided two arguments, mother() and \+X==_ to the \+(mother(),\+X==_) so the parser should still treat \+ as a valid functor with two arguments when given without space. Where am I wrong, please correct me.

Comment: What the error message indicates confirms what Jakub told you, that the parser treats \+ without the following space as asking for that functor to be applied as having two arguments.  While the syntax is "valid", there is no definition of predicate \+(2).  SWI-Prolog is by default proactive in labelling this as an error rather than just failing silently.  However if you prefer the latter, there is an option in SWI-Prolog to suppress the "error".  I think I sometimes double the nesting parentheses rather than use a space; have you tried that?

Comment: @hardmath Thank you for your reply. However what I still do not understand is(as was also the second part of my question) that why does the parser then not give an error on \+father(michael,cathy). Here too \+ is without space and there is no definition of \+father. Also, please note that the error message includes "there are definitions for: (\+)/1". Please help me clarifying it. Also thanks for the double parens suggestion, yes it worked.

Comment: Any character after the operator is OK for the parser, *except* the opening paren. If it's `\+father(...`, it knows that the operator name ends at the 'f'. If it's `\+(...`, it treats `\+` as the name of a functor, and indeed, you can use negation like `\+(something)`, as long as there is just one thing (no commas) inside the parens.

Comment: @JakubWasilewski Thank you for the explanation. I think I understand it now, and "\+(something)" is valid and probably that's the reason why the error message includes "However, there are definitions for: (\+)/1 ".

Comment: Posted a new answer - perhaps one that makes the rules and what is happening more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I think the explanation should be that Prolog doesn't allow a space between functor and arguments.

An operator is a functor with suitable declaration (see [op](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=op/3)/3 and [current_op](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_op/3)/3). After such declaration we can *choice* if to use the functor as operator or not. A contrived example, with arithmetic:

```
?- X is +(1,*(5,8)).
X = 41.

?- X is 1+5*8.
X = 41.

?- X is 1+(5*8).
X = 41.
```

Then the error you have seen is similar to this

```
?- X is + (1,*(5,8)).
ERROR: evaluable `1,5*8' does not exist
   Exception: (6) expand_goal(_G209 is + (1, 5*8), _G292, user, [user, system], _G295) ? creep
```

i.e. the atom `+` to be used as functor doesn't allows a space before parenthesis.

**edit**
Another thing worth of note is that `,` is declared as operator, meaning `AND`, *but* is also a lexical element, used as argument separator. Then in your second case the + is applied to the conjunction `mother(M,_) AND \+ X==_`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. However in the first case the parser takes \+ as an operator(if written with a space) and as a functor(if written without space) and gives an error since it is not defined. But in the second case, it takes \+ as an operator when given with space and as a functor if written without space but still doesn't give an error even though the functor is not defined here too, like in the previous case. Why does it treat both the cases differently when they are alike? I can't understand this. Also please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Ok, here is I got more confused. Isnt the negation operator `\+` taken as a whole or is it a combination of `\` and `+' working together? also, If thats the case as you said and it takes `,` as AND (which it actually is according to the predicate clause) why does it print an error saying "Undefined procedure: (\+)/2"? Doesn't this mean that the parser is taking `,` here as argument separator?

Comment: the comma serves 2 different purposes, the resolution it's context dependent (I think...)